# A problem with the rss feed of TeX.SX

Tags: bug, rss

I wanted to use ifttt.com for tracking new questions on TeX.SX, and after giving it the URL https://tex.stackexchange.com/feeds got an error "Not a valid feed url, missing feed title".  What might be going on?

Comment: Works for me with Firefox 12

Comment: @MartinScharrer: but what works?  RSS in FF or RSS in ifttt.com?  The former works for me, too, but the latter not.

Comment: The feed works for me with Firefox 12, I didn't tried ifttt.com. Maybe the issue lies with them.

Comment: Do you know Stack2RSS? Compare my answer: [RSS feed for New questions?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2410/9237).

Comment: Out of interest, is this still a problem?